# Integrating Google Maps VueJS Components (vue2-google-maps) into a Laravel blade view

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue2-google-maps

I am integrating a **Google Maps Vue JS** component into a **Laravel** application view using the **vue2-google-maps** npm package.

As per the [npm package documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps) I am loading the vue components from the npm package using:

```
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps';

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: 'mapkey',
    libraries: 'places'
  }
});
```

I am then using the components inside the blade view with the example code from the documentation:

```
    <GmapMap
      :center="{lat:10, lng:10}"
      :zoom="7"
      map-type-id="terrain"
      style="width: 100%; height: 500px" 
      id="googleMap"
    >
        <GmapMarker
            :key="index"
            v-for="(m, index) in mapPoints"
            :position="m.position"
            :clickable="true"
            :draggable="true"
            @click="center=m.position"
        >
        </GmapMarker>
    </GmapMap>
```

However, I receive the following error:

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component
>   correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name"
>   option.

---

After some research I came across [this post](https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-google-maps/), that used different component names, so I tried using the alternate component names **gmap-map** & **gmap-marker**, but this resulted in the same error.

```
<gmap-map
  :center="center"
  :zoom="12"
  style="width:100%;  height: 400px;"
>
  <gmap-marker
    :key="index"
    v-for="(m, index) in markers"
    :position="m.position"
    @click="center=m.position"
  ></gmap-marker>
</gmap-map>
```

---

I then tried importing the Map And Marker components directly instead of all the components recursively. However, this yields the same error:

```
import GmapMap from 'vue2-google-maps/src/components/map';
import GmapMarker from 'vue2-google-maps/src/components/marker';

Vue.component('GmapMap', GmapMap);
Vue.component('GmapMarker', GmapMarker);
```

---

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Components in the plugin only install when `installComponents` option to `true`.

https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/blob/v0.10.5/src/main.js#L69

```
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps';

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: 'mapkey',
    libraries: 'places'
  },
  installComponents: true
});
```